# Integration by using a suitable substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to integrate $\int_2^t x^3/\sqrt{x^4 - 2}$. I need to use a suitable substitution method; I tried letting $u=(x^4 - 2)$. I got the answer of $-1/4(\sqrt{t^4 - 2} - \sqrt{14})$; the actual answer apparently is the same but with 1/2 instead of -1/4.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Use the general formula for a differentiable function $\;f(x)\;$, which you can easily prove using the Chain Rule :

$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C$$

And then, since $\;(x^4-2)'=4x^3\;$ , we get

$$\int\limits_2^t\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^4-2}}dx=\frac14\int\limits_2^t\frac{4x^3}{\sqrt{x^4-2}}dx=\left.\frac12\sqrt{x^4-2}\right|_2^t=\frac12\left(\sqrt{t^4-2}-\sqrt{14}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{x^3dx}{\sqrt{x^4-2}}=\int \frac{du}{4\sqrt u}=\frac14\int u^{-\frac12}du=\frac14\frac{u^{\left(-\frac12+1\right)}}{\left(-\frac12+1\right)}+K$$

$$\text{as }\int x^mdx=\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+K$$ for $m+1\ne0\iff m\ne-1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{t}^{2}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^4-2}}dx=\int_{14}^{t^4-2}\frac{1}{4\sqrt u}du=\frac{1}{4}[2\sqrt u]_{14}^{t^4-2}$$
where $$du/dx=4x^3$$
I guess you misunderstood the last part, maybe forget $2$?